Sending multiple datasets or a signals channel to Deneb
Normally a single dataset is communicated to Deneb from within powerbi. What I'd like to do is send the Deneb visual parameter values.
One way that works is to combine a dataset with parameter values as columns, however this is not efficient if the data size is large.
For example, if the data has 100K rows, a single parameter value would have to be sent as an entire column with a single value repeated 100K times.
What would be better is if these parameters could be sent as another dataset with a single row.
Is there a way to do this or something similar?

This is not currently possible other than using the mechanism you have already described. Instead of sending the param 100k times, you could wrap in a measure that does a TOPN() and send just for the first row.
